# Docker - ELK - vm.max_map_count

Tags: elasticsearch, docker, docker-compose, elastic-stack

I'm trying to use the docker's image **elk-docker** (https://elk-docker.readthedocs.io/) , using Docker Compose. The .yml file, is like this:

```
elk:
image: sebp/elk
ports:
  - "5601:5601"
  - "9200:9200"
  - "5044:5044"
```

When I run the command: sudo docker-compose up, the console shows:

```
* Starting Elasticsearch Server
sysctl: setting key "vm.max_map_count": Read-only file system
...fail!
waiting for Elasticsearch to be up (1/30)
waiting for Elasticsearch to be up (2/30)
waiting for Elasticsearch to be up (3/30)
waiting for Elasticsearch to be up (4/30)
waiting for Elasticsearch to be up (5/30)
waiting for Elasticsearch to be up (6/30)
waiting for Elasticsearch to be up (7/30)
waiting for Elasticsearch to be up (8/30)
waiting for Elasticsearch to be up (9/30)
waiting for Elasticsearch to be up (10/30)
waiting for Elasticsearch to be up (11/30)
waiting for Elasticsearch to be up (12/30)
waiting for Elasticsearch to be up (13/30)
waiting for Elasticsearch to be up (14/30)
waiting for Elasticsearch to be up (15/30)
waiting for Elasticsearch to be up (16/30)
waiting for Elasticsearch to be up (17/30)
waiting for Elasticsearch to be up (18/30)
waiting for Elasticsearch to be up (19/30)
waiting for Elasticsearch to be up (20/30)
waiting for Elasticsearch to be up (21/30)
waiting for Elasticsearch to be up (22/30)
waiting for Elasticsearch to be up (23/30)
waiting for Elasticsearch to be up (24/30)
waiting for Elasticsearch to be up (25/30)
waiting for Elasticsearch to be up (26/30)
waiting for Elasticsearch to be up (27/30)
waiting for Elasticsearch to be up (28/30)
waiting for Elasticsearch to be up (29/30)
waiting for Elasticsearch to be up (30/30)
Couln't start Elasticsearch. Exiting.
Elasticsearch log follows below.
cat: /var/log/elasticsearch/elasticsearch.log: No such file or directory
docker_elk_1 exited with code 1
```

How can I resolve the problem?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You probably need to set `vm.max_map_count` in `/etc/sysctl.conf` on the host itself, so that Elasticsearch does not attempt to do that from inside the container. If you don't know the desired value, try doubling the current setting and keep going until Elasticsearch starts successfully. [Documentation recommends](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/5.1/docker.html#docker-cli-run-prod-mode) at least 262144.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I set vm.max_map_count in the sysctl.conf file with 262144, but the cosole shows the same error.

Comment: Did you reboot the host? If you want to change the setting dynamically, use `sysctl vm.max_map_count` to check what value is in effect.

Comment: Yes, I run the command vm.max_map_count, and it showed me: vm.max_map_count = 262144

Comment: I've run into this as well and some discussion has taken place about solutions for macOS hosts, but I'm unsure of any impact to Windows.  Before Docker v1.13 this was simple enough to solve (`docker-machine ssh` and run `sudo sysctl -w vm.max_map_count=262144`).  Now that Docker for macOS is using the xhyve virtual machine, replace the `docker-machine ssh` step with `screen ~/Library/Containers/com.docker.docker/Data/com.docker.driver.amd64-linux/tty `.  Source: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/master/docker.html#docker-cli-run-prod-mode

Comment: Side effects when increasing vm.max_map_count: https://www.novell.com/support/kb/doc.php?id=7000830

Comment: How to do it if the host machine is a MacOS?

Comment: If using [RancherOS](https://rancher.com/docs/os/v1.x/en/installation/configuration/sysctl/), need to create a [yaml file](https://gist.github.com/janeczku/02302dae3fbfa011f4f7a60df2b5f24e#file-sysctl-config-yml) and apply config with ```sudo ros config merge -i sysctl-config.yml``` then reboot.

Answer (score 29):

You can do that in 2 ways.

1. **Temporary set max_map_count**:

   - sudo sysctl -w vm.max_map_count=262144

     but this will only last till you restart your system.
2. **Permament**

   - In your host machine

     - vi /etc/sysctl.conf
     - make entry 
       vm.max_map_count=262144
     - restart

Comment: I had this issue when I tried to run Docker container with Elasticsearch (8.3.3) on Manjaro Linux. Setting `max_map_count` helped.

Answer (score 9):

In Docker host terminal (Docker CLI) run commands:

```
docker-machine ssh
sudo sysctl -w vm.max_map_count=262144
exit
```

Answer (score 3):

1. Go inside your docker container

   ```
   # docker exec -it <container_id> /bin/bash
   ```
2. You can view your current *max_map_count* value

   ```
   # more /proc/sys/vm/max_map_count
   ```
3. Temporary set *max_map_count* value(container(host) restart will not persist *max_map_count* value)

   ```
   # sysctl -w vm.max_map_count=262144
   ```
4. Permanently set value

   ```
   1. # vi /etc/sysctl.conf
        vm.max_map_count=262144

   2. # vi /etc/rc.local 
        #put parameter inside rc.local file
        echo 262144 > /proc/sys/vm/max_map_count
   ```

Answer (score 0):

You have to set the **vm.max_map_count** variable in /etc/sysctl.conf at least with 262144

After that you can reload the settings with **sysctl --system**