# macOS Docker Desktop with ElasticSearch 7.10.0 not running - ERROR: [1] bootstrap checks failed, exit code 78

Tags: macos, docker, elasticsearch

It stops automatically after running for a couple seconds with the error below:

```
ERROR: [1] bootstrap checks failed

ERROR: Elasticsearch did not exit normally - check the logs at /usr/share/elasticsearch/logs/docker-cluster.log
```

Many posts say it's because I need to increase `vm.max_map_count` to at least `262144`, including the official doc for `ElasticSearch`:
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docker.html#docker-cli-run-prod-mode

But I am unable to run `docker-machine ssh`, and I'm not sure why all of a sudden I need to use docker machine? I'm getting this error: `Error: No machine name(s) specified and no "default" machine exists`

Nor could I do: `screen ~/Library/Containers/com.docker.docker/Data/vms/0/tty`

`tty` does not exist in this directory, so the screen is terminating.

I can't just straight up do `sysctl -w vm.max_map_count=262144` like many posts from and before the year 2018. This is what I'm getting: `sysctl: unknown oid 'vm.max_map_count'`

And this https://stackoverflow.com/a/41065159/14985824 doesn't work either, I do not have a `sysctl.config` file in that directory.

I'm not sure why this person is running a `debian` container, or maybe it's just because I don't really understand what is happening with method 1: https://stackoverflow.com/a/63595817/14985824

I'm looking at the `Images on disk` section on docker desktop, it tells me `Total size: 1.11 GB`, and they are all in use. Wondering if it has anything to do with this issue?

I have been struggling for a long time, please send help, thank you!

Edit:
After trying to increase docker memory from 2GB to 3GB, I'm getting the following:

```
ERROR: [1] bootstrap checks failed

[1]: the default discovery settings are unsuitable for production use; at least one of [discovery.seed_hosts, discovery.seed_providers, cluster.initial_master_nodes] must be configured

ERROR: Elasticsearch did not exit normally - check the logs at /usr/share/elasticsearch/logs/docker-cluster.log
```

Answer (score -1):

Let me just answer my own question. Because I'm running multiple containers at the same time, so the ES container + Postgres container. So it works with a proper docker-compose.yml file

Comment: Can you share what your docker-compose.yml is and how it was different from the one elastisearch provided?  I am running into the same situation